# OpenMediaVault / Debian won't recognize new network

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a server with OpenMediaVault (which runs on Debian) it had been configured for my home network but I moved to a new place with a new router and new network (router is set to assign IPs with DHCP). I plugged an ethernet cable in the server but it's still using its old settings and I cannot find him on my current network (router doesn't see him connected, either).

I tried restarting it and tried to tell it to get new configuration but am not that savvy and I don't remember exactly what I did (sorry, it's been hectic moving).

I have physical access to it and it has a keyboard and monitor, which is how I'm currently interacting with it.

This is my `nano /etc/resolv.conf` output (typed by hand from what I saw on the screen):

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all condigured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

This is my `nano /etc/network/interfaces` output (typed by hand from what I saw on the screen):

```
# This file is auto-generated by openmediavault (https://www.openmediavault.org)
# WARNING: Do not edit this file, your changes will get lost.

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Better use netplan.io or systemd-networkd to configure additional interface stanzas.

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Output from `iftables -a` (typed by hand from what I saw on the screen, also omitting kubernetes interfaces and etc.):

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP, BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.15.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.15.255
        ether --skipping this line as am not sure whether I should post it on the net--
        RX packets 607984 bytes 52335391 (49.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0 dropped 6 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 21334 bytes 1759560 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
        device interrupt 20 memory 0xf3100000-f3120000
        
lo: flags:73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 151863 bytes 56908700 (54.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0 dropped 6 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 151863 bytes 56908700 (54.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Output from `ip a` (typed by hand from what I saw on the screen, also omitting kubernetes interfaces and etc.):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1 scope host line
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether --skipping this line as am not sure whether I should post it on the net--
    inet 192.168.15.101/24 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global enp0s25
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ifdown enp0s25`:

`ifdown: interface enp0s25 not configured`

Output of `ifup eth0`:

`ifup: unknown interface eth0`

My current network is 192.168.50.*

I have no idea what is happenning.

Comment: You might want to have a look into the files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`

Comment: @mashuptwice, why, how, etc. Your comment isn't helping at all. What are those files, why should I have a look at them and, considering I'm no expert, what ought I see there?

Comment: Obviously your `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains the two lines `# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d` which could lead to the assumption that you could find the network configuration of your system there. You can use `cat` `nano` `vim` `emacs` or any other text viewer/editor to look at the files on a unixoidal system like debian. Another hint in the exact same file is `Better use netplan.io or systemd-networkd to configure additional interface stanzas.` [systemd-network](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-networkd)

Comment: @mashuptwice, that's great! I have no idea what to do with that information. :) No offense, but that's like saying "Obviously your electromagnetic relay is fried and you need to reconfigure your plasma drive." to a native american in the 18th century. I have no understanding on this topic and would appreciate more detailed instructions, which you are not obliged to provide.

Comment: It seems that you are missing basic knowledge about directories and files, don't know anything about basic file editors and/or you are unable to read. You might want to learn about linux basics, or pay a professional if you want to resolve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: You could try `omv-firstaid` from the console and have your network reconfigured.